# Convert JSON array of arrays to data.frame

Tags: r, json

here is my context-:

```
 context<- '[["2014-01-01","192.168.1.1",41],["2014-01-02","192.168.1.1",30],["2014-01-03","192.168.1.1",25],["2014-01-04","192.168.1.1",0],["2014-01-05","192.168.1.1",0],["2014-01-06","192.168.1.1",30],["2014-01-07","192.168.1.1",40],["2014-01-08","192.168.1.1",41],["2014-01-09","192.168.1.1",30],["2014-01-10","192.168.1.1",25],["2014-01-11","192.168.1.1",0],["2014-01-12","192.168.1.1",0],["2014-01-13","192.168.1.1",30],["2014-01-14","192.168.1.1",40],["2014-01-15","192.168.1.1",40],["2014-01-16","192.168.1.1",30],["2014-01-17","192.168.1.1",25],["2014-01-18","192.168.1.1",0],["2014-01-19","192.168.1.1",0],["2014-01-20","192.168.1.1",30],["2014-01-21","192.168.1.1",40],["2014-01-22","192.168.1.1",40],["2014-01-23","192.168.1.1",30],["2014-01-24","192.168.1.1",25],["2014-01-25","192.168.1.1",0],["2014-01-26","192.168.1.1",0],["2014-01-27","192.168.1.1",30],["2014-01-28","192.168.1.1",40],["2014-01-29","192.168.1.1",41],["2014-01-30","192.168.1.1",30],["2014-01-31","192.168.1.1",25],["2014-02-01","192.168.1.1",0],["2014-02-02","192.168.1.1",0],["2014-02-03","192.168.1.1",30],["2014-02-04","192.168.1.1",40],["2014-02-05","192.168.1.1",40],["2014-02-06","192.168.1.1",30],["2014-02-07","192.168.1.1",25],["2014-02-08","192.168.1.1",0],["2014-02-09","192.168.1.1",0],["2014-02-10","192.168.1.1",30],["2014-02-11","192.168.1.1",40],["2014-02-12","192.168.1.1",40]]'
```

help me to convert this in dataframe 
i did this

```
    > data_context<-fromJSON(context)
    > data <-
      data.frame(
       "timeslice" = data_context[, 1],
      "host" = data_context[, 2],
     "metric" = as.numeric(data_context[, 3])
     )
```

it does not work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like the following:

```
library(rjson)
step1 <- fromJSON(context) 
setNames(
  data.frame(do.call(rbind, step1)), 
  c("timeslice", "host", "metric")
)

    timeslice        host metric
1  2014-01-01 192.168.1.1     41
2  2014-01-02 192.168.1.1     30
3  2014-01-03 192.168.1.1     25
4  2014-01-04 192.168.1.1      0
5  2014-01-05 192.168.1.1      0
6  2014-01-06 192.168.1.1     30
..
```

Comment: BRO , you are simply awesome

Comment: do one more thing , please change name to which i mentioned